# active_model_serializers, includes, and why a serializer is querying data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, json-api

When working with API, I am used to:

1. execute some DB queries
2. select the data I want in my response
3. serialize the data, and send it to the client

*Now*, using **active_model_serializers**, I was assuming that in

`render json: artist, include: 'tracks'`

the `include: 'tracks'` part would serialize `tracks`, if my artist had some tracks.

But apparently, it will also fetch the tracks from the db for me.

**Is it a normal behaviour** ? Is the serializer supposed to make db queries ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to include a association it first has to be fetched from the database. Otherwise how can it be included in the response?

See the [json serializer documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json).

The association is called by it's corresponding method. In your example that would be *Artist#tracks*. (See the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/375a4143cf5caeb6159b338be824903edfd62836/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L186).) **This means that if you load the association before calling the serializer it will not call the database.**

Example:

```
artist = Artist.first # <= artists table gets queried
artist.tracks.load # <= tracks table gets queried
render json: artist, include: :tracks # <= no queries
```

Comment: ok, so in rails: _serilalize_ = _serialize_ + **query missing data from db** , right ?

Comment: Yes. The only alternatives would be: 1. Raise an error that it can't render because of missing data. 2. Set an error on a relevant object and return false as result (like with *ActiveRecord::Base*). But the implementation in my answer is where the Rails developers went with.